# How to load new posts from wordpress db into wordpress homepage without refreshing the site?

Tags: comments

```
4.5
Hasan Mahmud to Madhevere, no run
4.4
Hasan Mahmud to Madhevere, no run, good length delivery outside off stump, Madhevere defends off the back foot
4.3
Hasan Mahmud to Madhevere, no run, full delivery, Madhevere drives towards cover
4.2
Hasan Mahmud to Madhevere, no run, short of length delivery, Madhevere keeps it out
4.2
Hasan Mahmud to Madhevere, wide, fired down leg
4.1
Hasan Mahmud to Madhevere, no run, full delivery outside off stump, Madhevere looks to drive, hits it on the bounce to mid-off
```

This types of commentaries are added to my wordpress db after every 'x' seconds. When I am in the homepage currently, If I want to show the new commentary, I need to refresh the site. Is it possible to show the commentaries without refreshing the site?

Comment: Almost anything is possible, but you're asking about third party services that are completely unrelated to WordPress, so it's not possible to say how to add them to WordPress unless you already have code that gets the commentaries you want and can share it.

Comment: I already have that commentaries in wordpress post. So, my question is where there will be a new post in wordpress db, I want to show it wordpress homepage without reloading the homepage.

Comment: Then that's the question you should've asked. You should update the question to ask about what you currently need. If the commentaries are already being added as posts then Espncricinfo and Cricbuzz are completely irrelevant.

Comment: Edited the question. Can you please help now?